# Conditional Expectation of Random Functional

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $h$ be an $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$-valued integrable random variable that is jointly measurable, i.e. $h\in L^1(\mathbb{P}; L^1(\mathbb{R}^n))$ and $(\omega, x)\mapsto h(\omega)(x)$ is $\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{B}^n$-measurable.

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$. Does it hold for suitable $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued r.v.'s $x$ that
$$\omega\mapsto E(h\vert \mathcal{G})(\omega)(x(\omega)) = E\big(\omega\mapsto h(\omega)(x(\omega))\big\vert \mathcal{G}\big)\quad \text{in $L^0(\mathbb{P})$} ?$$

Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining $E[h|\mathcal G]$?

Comment: @user6247850 $E(h|\mathcal{G})$ satisfies $\int_A h \mathbb{P} = \int_A E(h|\mathcal{G}) \mathbb{P}$ for all $A\in\mathcal{G}$ (here the integral is the Banach-space valued Bochner integral).